# Why is transaction is not rolling back if one query failed?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

Below code i just not add third parameter in `fQuery` statement , second query is correct. but as i understand that transaction provide Atomicity if first query is failed than second should not be executed but in my code first query give error & second query executed successfully.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=stock",'root','') ;

$name = 'name' ;
$mobile = 1234567890 ;
$email = 'email@gmail.com'  ;

try {

    $db->beginTransaction();

    $fQuery = "INSERT INTO investor (name,mobile,email) values (:n,:m,:e) " ;
    $fstmt = $db->prepare($fQuery) ;
    $fstmt->execute([':n'=>$name,':m'=>$mobile]);

    $sQuery = "INSERT INTO testing (name) values (:e) " ;
    $sstmt = $db->prepare($sQuery) ;
    $sstmt->execute([':e'=>$email]);

    $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: apply this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php to your code; what does it show?

Comment: you're trying to deliberately cause an error; that isn't how you check if a query/transaction failed or not. The query itself must be valid; the first one will fail as a syntax error.

Comment: Might be because passing fewer parameters to `PDOStatement::execute()` triggers a PHP Warning (SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number) - it's not an exception and therefore cannot be caught.

Comment: @Darragh  yes `email` is nullable column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO won't throw exceptions unless you tell it to.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```